# Некорректная работа функции sizeof()

Tags: c++

В процессе разработки, заметил некорректную работу программы, вынес проблему в отдельный проект.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getSize(int arr[]) {
    return sizeof(arr);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    cout << getSize(arr) << endl; // Вывод: 8
    cout << sizeof(arr) << endl;  // Вывод: 16

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас вводит в заблуждение объявление функции `int getSize(int arr[])`. `arr` в нем является обычным указателем, а не массивом. Если хотите получить размер массива, то нужен шаблон, принимающий массив по ссылке:

```
template<typename T, ::std::size_t items_count> ::std::size_t
getSize(T ( & arr )[items_count])
{
     return sizeof(arr);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/abNTtU40WIPRM76n)

А вообще вместо С-style массивов следует использовать `std::array`.

Answer (score 2):

для функции  `getSize`  имя вашего массива является указателем (ваша функция не знает  какой массив вы ей передадите).
Поэтому выводится размер указателья.
В `main()` вы имеет определенный массив, и `sizeof` выдает размер  всего массива;

Answer (score 0):

При передаче в функцию `int arr[]` эквивалентно `int *arr`, поэтому ты получаешь размер указателя, а не размер массива.

Для Си++ можно сделать так: https://ideone.com/2v0qXE

```
template <int N> int getSize(int (&arr)[N]) {
    return sizeof(arr);
}
```

Но вообще гораздо лучше в функцию передавать размер массива, а не пытаться его там вычислить. Ну и ещё для размеров правильнее использовать `size_t`, а не `int`.

Comment: Вы наступаете на те же грабли, в записи `int arr[N]` параметр `arr` будет указателем.

Comment: @VTT этот код при вызове без явного указания значения аргумента N даже не соберется, потому что неоткуда вывести значение N.

Comment: @VTT, да, забыл, что надо было ссылку делать.

Comment: @Croessmah, я исправил. Ну забыл про ссылку - чего сразу набрасываться-то?